# Why does sha256sum not accept its own output under windows?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, sha256

I want to check files with `sha256sum -c file.sha` under Windows, using the sha256sum.exe from my git installation.
I'm trying to create the checksum files with `sha256sum -b file.exe > file.sha`.
But sha256sum is complaining: `no properly formatted SHA256 checksum lines found`.

Here is the complete procedure with my cscope.exe as an example:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin> .\sha256sum.exe -b 'D:\Tools\Cscope\cscope.exe' > 'D:\Tools\Cscope\cscope.sha'
PS C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin> cat 'D:\Tools\Cscope\cscope.sha'
\3f8c98e1571cd36878a3d2eab33b9859f2d03d79d7dc3f6c52afca957e76526f *D:\\Tools\\Cscope\\cscope.exe
PS C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin> .\sha256sum.exe -c 'D:\Tools\Cscope\cscope.sha'
/usr/bin/sha256sum: 'D:\Tools\Cscope\cscope.sha': no properly formatted SHA256 checksum lines found
PS C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin>
```

Any idea why this does not work?
How should the sha file be formatted to be accepted by sha256sum.exe?

Comment: How does it related to powershell ? (you tagged it)

Comment: `>` is an alias to `Out-File` which use UTF-16 encoding by default. Which is likely not what `sha256sum.exe` expect.

Comment: @E235 I used Powershell to invoke the command. It could be part of the problem that I used PS instead of cmd.

Comment: @PetSerAl yes that's the point. I converted the file to latin-1 and voila! Thank you. You could set your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Why is this question marked as duplicate? The reason for this behaviour turns out to be the same as in the supposed duplicate question but the question is completely different. The behaviour of the `>` operator is part of the answer, not part of my question! I's not obvious to the Powershell amateur that the operator is responsible for the problem here.

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate because both the underlying problem and the solution are identical. Whether the output is generated by `echo` or `sha256sum` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, but it is not irrelevant that sha256sum cannot handle UTF-16 encoded inputs.

Comment: There's nothing (necessarily) wrong with a duplicate question, certainly not in this case.  It helps other people find the answer.  There's no point in posting the same answer, or essentially the same answer, to multiple similar questions, and that's what the duplicate quesiton mechanism is for.